# How to pass a table key in a function for use in a for loop?

Tags: lua

For some reason it doesn't appear to work to pass in a table key as a function argument, what is the trick to do this?

I'm trying to wrap the for loop iteration technique in vanilla Lua into a function that has three arguments: (1) the table to iterate, (2) the table_key to check each time, and (3) the value to find. If a match is found, return it, otherwise return nil.

```
function table_find_match(table, table_key, match_value)
    for i=1, #table do
        local this = table[i]
        if this[table_key] == match_value then
            return this[table_key]
        end
    end
    return nil
end

local table_example = {
    {
        key_example = "string_value_1"
    },
    {
        key_example = "string_value_2"
    }
}

local result = table_find_match(table_example, key_example, "string_value_1")
print(result)
```

Comment: Here in "table_find_match" call you're not passing the "key_example" value, you're reading the value of a variable "key_example", and since it doesn't exist, the function receives nil. You have to pass the value of the key, and when it's a string value, double-quote the text, that's just normal and correct, there's nothing to dislike.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, if I pass in the table key as a string it works, such as

```
table_find_match(table_example, "key_example", "string_value_1")
```

but I really dislike having to convert it into a string, if anyone knows any other workaround to this please share

Comment: Keys are strings. They can be variables holding strings, however.

Comment: @tonypdmtr No, not in general. A key is any value other than `nil` and NaN. [Ref 2.1 – Values and Types](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1). As @Vlad explained and as shown in [Ref 3.4.9 – Table Constructors](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9) the keys in the inner tables in the question do happen to be strings.

Comment: In a table constructor, there is syntactic sugar to convert bare word keys to strings. If you wanted the key to be a variable (or any other expression), you could put `[]` around it. In most other code, there's no way for a bare word to be interpreted as anything other than a variable, so you have to use quotes if you mean it to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass it like `table_find_match(table_example, key_example, "string_value_1")`
the key_example is now considered as a (nil) variable if not defined before executing, so it has to be like

```
local key_example = "key_example"
local result = table_find_match(table_example, key_example, "string_value_1")
print(result)
```